# How to assign application window to a specific hotkey on a MacOS?

Tags: macos

For example: safari is always `command + 1` 
chrome is always `command + 2` 
terminal is always `command + 3` etc 
Window arrangement **should not influence** hotkey combination.

Comment: this "how to use macos" question might be more appropriate to be asked on https://apple.stackexchange.com/